# How do I run Backendless with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, backendless

I cannot get Backendless to compile in Xcode 8 with iOS 10 and Swift 3. I have updated to the latest version of Backendless-iOS-SDK via CocoaPods. Every time I try to compile, I am met with numerous errors in the parts of my code that access the Backendless SDK. Every time I fix the errors, countless more appear when I try to run. This makes me think I have done something wrong during the process of upgrading the SDK.

- Any ideas what could be happening here? Is it expected that all my code that accesses Backendless needs to be changed when upgrading to Swift 3? (Please note that I have ALREADY Converted to the latest Swift 3 syntax).
- Is the Backendless SDK now compatible with Xcode 8 and Swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas what could be happening here? Is it expected that all my code that accesses Backendless needs to be changed when upgrading to Swift 3? (Please note that I have ALREADY Converted to the latest Swift 3 syntax).

Yes, you might need to change the code if its not converted by the migrator.

> Is the Backendless SDK now compatible with Xcode 8 and Swift 3?

Yes, because the Backendless SDK is in Objective C so there will be no issues using it.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue on swift3 installation via cocoa pod as of the moment.. please use option 2 in the documentation... importing the lib adding it manually is better.